# Plotly Takes to long to Render an output

Tags: python, plotly, geojson

I need a help please :)

Hi! I have a dataframe CSV file in which I have longitude column, latitude column, and sales.
I would love to visualize my data geographically.

First I have tried to do a scatters directly CSV and wrote the next.

```
px.set_mapbox_access_token("my token on mapbox")
fig = px.scatter_mapbox(df, lat="latitude", lon="longitude",color="sales",
                  color_continuous_scale=px.colors.cyclical.IceFire, size_max=20,zoom=12)
fig.show()
fig.write_html("example_map.html")
```

It has never opened.

Then I have tried to try without mapbox and converted CSV into Json file.

```
import csv
import json
from collections import OrderedDict

li = []
with open("Path  to my file") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        d = OrderedDict()
        d['type'] = 'zipCode'
        d['geometry'] = {
            'type': 'Point',
            'coordinates': [float(row['latitude']), float(row['longitude'])]
        }
        li.append(d)

d = OrderedDict()
d['type'] = 'FeatureCollection'
d['features'] = li

with open('output.json','w') as f:
    json.dump(d,f,indent=2)
```

and next I have tried to plot it:

```
import csv
import json
from collections import OrderedDict

li = []
with open("C:\\Users\\Dell\\Desktop\\Intern 2021\\McGill\\full_dataset_csv.csv", newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        d = OrderedDict()
        d['type'] = 'zipCode'
        d['geometry'] = {
            'type': 'Point',
            'coordinates': [float(row['latitude']), float(row['longitude'])]
        }
        li.append(d)

d = OrderedDict()
d['type'] = 'FeatureCollection'
d['features'] = li

with open('output.json','w') as f:
    json.dump(d,f,indent=2)
```

Again it took forever to show an output. I think I might have done something wrong in codding? Or I should think about an alternative to Plotly?

Comment: I think that's because the data you have is very big!

Comment: Which takes more time, the time to acquire data or the time to draw a graph?